# Getting Repeater values from code behind

Tags: .net, vb.net, webforms, repeater

I'd like to get a repeater values from code behind after pressed a BUTTON. But in my code-behind, the repeater always came "0". I mean Nothing.

I's my repeater in an aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceU">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Car Type</th>
                <th>Cars</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUnitTypeValue" Text='<%# Eval("CarTypeName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <th>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCars"
                        runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceViews"
                        DataTextField="problemLocationName"
                        DataValueField="problemLocationId"
                        Width="212px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViews"
                        runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [problemLocationId],[problemLocationName] FROM [ProblemLocation]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </th>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QfsAdminConnectionString %>"
        ID="SqlDataSourceU" runat="server"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CarTypeName] FROM [CarType]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It's my code-behind. It doesn't enter in my `foreach` loop, because always come with nothing. But it's not true, there are values in my repeater. 
So I`d like to press the button and gets the values from my repeater.

```
Protected Sub btnSaveDefaultView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDefaultView.Click
    Dim itens As Repeater = CType(ViewDefaultView.FindControl("RepeaterUnitTypes"), Repeater)

    For Each item In itens.Items

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure but this might work : `For each item as (your item type) in itens` Read more about `For Each...Next` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement

Comment: Do you mean that the variable "itens" is Nothing?

Comment: Yes, I mean that the variable is Nothing.

Comment: I don't know much about vb.net but in c# you have to bind the data to the repeater. Have you done that here?

Comment: My God, there's a lot of misconception going on here.
Are you trying to edit all the records at once using just one repeater?
Oh Lord!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get values from repeater and there is no need to find a repeater:

```
For Each rItem As RepeaterItem In MyRepeater.Items
  Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(rItem.FindControl("lblUnitTypeValue"), Label)
  If Not IsNothing(lbl) Then
    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text)
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Horse Awnser here!

Parse the html generated by Repeater as JSON '[CarType]' object and ajax it to the server.

VOALÁ